# vb.net update access record with 2 Where clauses

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, records

I am getting a syntax error while trying to use 2 Where values from my database to make an update to the "IddeEmpleado" Employee ID in which "Fecha" which means Date. The employee already clocked in, and I want to update when it clock outs in the same line I got the clock in hour.

```
 Private Sub btnClockout_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClockout.Click
    Dim ds As New DataSet()

    Dim connString As String


    Dim myConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection
    connString = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = ..\Bases de Datos\Horario.accdb"
    myConnection.ConnectionString = connString

    myConnection.Open()

    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("select * from Empleado where IdDeEmpleado like '%" + txtEmpId.Text + "%'", myConnection)
    Dim Adpt As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)

    If (Adpt.Fill(ds, "Empleado")) Then

        Dim con2 As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = ..\Bases de Datos\Horario.accdb")



        Try
            Dim Finalizoturno As Object
            Finalizoturno = DateTimePicker1.Text

            con2.Open()

            Dim updateQuery As String = "Update EmpleadoHorario Set FinalizoTurno= '" & DateTimePicker1.Text & "' Where Fecha= '" & datePicker.Text & " ' AND IddeEmpleado = '" & txtEmpId.Text & "'"

            Dim cmd2 As New OleDbCommand(updateQuery, con2)

            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()





            MessageBox.Show("Salida de Turno Aceptada")

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

        Finally
            con2.Dispose()

            End Try
            con2.Close()

        Else

            MessageBox.Show("ID de Empleado no encontrado")




        End If
        myConnection.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: Use parameters. The string representation of a datetime is not a datetime

Comment: Is `Fecha` a datetime column on the database?  If so, you're comparing it to a string.

Comment: Also you add a spare space after the value for Fecha

Comment: Fecha is a date column short date, I can update the database If I remove the IDdeEmpleado at the end. but I cannot get it to work with Fecha and IddeEmpleado

Comment: What type is IdDeEmpleado in the database? Is it the Primary Key of the table?

Comment: yes. id de empleado is the primary key

Comment: If you use parameters as @Steve suggests you won't get confused in the data types and string literals since parameterization will take care of that (example in pseudocode: `Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Fecha", SqlDbType.Date)).Value = datePicker.Text`). Also by parameterizing the code, it is generally more secure.

Comment: Also if `IdDeEmpleado` is the table key, I am guessing it is an integer... although Access may implicitly convert to an integer, you're passing a string. This would *also* be fixed by parameterizing the code...

Comment: There is a much room for improvement in that code.  Gluing things together is not the correct way to build SQL. As mentioned Dates are not strings and string s are not dates;  since dates do not have a format, that wont matter if you are using dates.  Finally, *anything* which implements the `Dispose` method needs to be disposed of.  `Using` blocks make this easy.  I'd argue that a local dataadpter is a waste given what they can be set up to do.  Also read [ask] and take the [tour] to learn how to use the site more effectively.

Comment: @JacobH thanks for the info, it was that... I needed the parameter, now it works perfect. Sorry for me been a noob. I am still learning on school, I need more practice.

Answer (score 1):

First and forever, turn on Option Strict in Project Properties, Compile tab.

2. You are creating objects you don't need. A DataSet and a DataAdapter are not necessay to just get the count.
3. You can initialize your connection in one line by passing the connection string to the constructor.
4. Don't open you connection until right before you need it.
5. A Primary Key is never duplicated so it makes no sense to use a Like clause in your query. You are just checking if the ID exists. Don't retrieve data when all you need is a count.
6. Use parameters. Acces cares not what the name of the parameter is, just the order; so make sure you add the parameters in the same order they appear in the query.
7. It is rare to need to declare a variable as Object. Finalizoturno is a Date so declate it as such. The Value property of a DateTimePicker returns a date, the Text property returns a string.

`

```
Private Sub btnClockout_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClockout.Click
    Dim myConnection As New OleDbConnection("PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = ..\Bases de Datos\Horario.accdb")
    Dim updateQuery As String = "Update EmpleadoHorario Set FinalizoTurno= ? Where Fecha= ? AND IddeEmpleado = ?;"
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(updateQuery, myConnection)
    Try
        cmd.Parameters.Add("Fecha1", OleDbType.Date).Value = DateTimePicker1.Value
        cmd.Parameters.Add("Fecha2", OleDbType.Date).Value = datePicker.Value
        cmd.Parameters.Add("ID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = CInt(txtEmpId.Text)
        myConnection.Open()
        Dim retVal As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        myConnection.Close()
        If retVal = 1 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Salida de Turno Aceptada")
        Else               
            MessageBox.Show("ID de Empleado no encontrado")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        cmd.Dispose()
        myConnection.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
```

`

Comment: @zackraiyan The only thing he does with his first query is 'If (Adpt.Fill(ds, "Empleado")) Then' He is simply checking in the EmpId exists, Count is one.

Comment: @Codexer I agree. Really don't need to check for existence just check the return value of the update to determine success. I will try to change my code.